# One sample case test on means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

A recent reporter indicated that waiters and waitresses at casual dining restaurants make an average of $\$100$ per night in tips with a standard deviation of $\$15$. Maureen works in a casual dining restaurant and doesn't think this is correct. She feels she makes much less than this in an average night. Over the next five work nights, she computes her tips and the average is $\$95$. Does Maureen make significantly less than what the report stated at the $1\%$ level of significance?

Answer (score 1):

First establish your null and alternative hypothesis. Then have a look at the [Z-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test) and [Student's t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test). Afterwards, study your data, specifically your sample size, and decide which of the two tests would work best and how you should apply them to your null and alternative.

The question is quite simple and can't really say more without fully giving out the answer. I've already said quite a lot. Good luck and have fun learning statistics.